# Rails API Grape | content-type is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, error-handling, ruby-grape

```
module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    prefix 'api'

    content_type :json, 'application/json'
    format :json
    default_format :json

    rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
      error!({ error: [{ msg: 'card's information is incorrect' }] }, 400)
    end

    rescue_from :all

    mount API::Ver1::Poker
  end
end
```

This is my API's root.
If I request something in JSON format, this API returns correct value.
However, if I request something in other formats such as Text or XML, this API returns like below.

```
{
    "error": "The provided content-type 'text/plain' is not supported."
}
```

or

```
{
    "error": "The provided content-type 'application/xml' is not supported."
}
```

I want to show error message 'cards information is incorrect'.

Why does not the following validation code work?

```
rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
    error!({ error: [{ msg: 'card's information is incorrect' }] }, 400)
end
```

Comment: `rescue_from :all` also dose not work, and API returns `"error": "The provided content-type 'text/plain' is not supported."` with status code 415.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the `content-type` to `json`, so it won't accept any other `content-type`.

If you wish to support all `content-types`

- either remvoe `content type:json,'application/json` line

OR

- add all of the 'content-types' you want to support.

  ```
  content_type :json, 'application/json'
  content_type :xml, 'application/xml'
  content_type :txt, 'text/plain'
  ```

Read more about [grape API formats](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#api-formats)

Comment: Thanks!!!
BTW, can I set other content_type except json, xml, txt and binary on grape?

Comment: I think no. From the Grape Readme > `Grape will support XML, JSON, BINARY, and TXT content-types`